# Google API PHP Client: first step, LOGIN

Tags: php, google-oauth

I'm trying to use the Google API PHP Client, but in the documentation I see this as first thing to do (find the ClientSecret):

```
    ...
    $client->setClientId('267094288212-gu0dcohtjpcj7msv2fkq97grp8cftdur.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('DONT-KNOW-WHERE-TO-FIND-IT');
    ...
```

My problem is simple to describe: I don't know WHERE to find the "ClientSecret". In settings (at this link: https://console.developers.google.com/project/gwtdata/apiui/credential)  I see the following information: where is it? Which "red number" I should use?

(here is the screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1880383/shot-google.png)

Thanks in advance!
Francesco

Answer (score 2):

When you created a new client id, you chose to create a service account, which is why you don't get a client-secret.

Instead, for application type, choose "Web Application", which will generate a client-secret for you to use in the php client.

[image: screenshot of application type option]